# Find the max allocated heap size during the execution using VM command line?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I wonder if I can obtain the maximum size of the `allocated heap` using VM command line.

From now I'm able to get it using `Netbeans Profiler` but I prefer getting result without have to launch an extra application.

I'm also using this method :

```
public void printMemUsage(){
        double currentMemory = ( (double)((double)(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1024.0)))- ((double)((double)(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1024.0)));
        System.out.println("Current memory usage in kilobytes :"+currentMemory);
}
```

I think I can use this to get the maximum heap size too but I'm not sure if it's very reliable.

I currently use those command lines :

> -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime

In order to get good information about gc activity, young generation, old and permanent. But I just can tell the current total heap space when collections occurs.

So is there a way to get the max heap space that have been alocated using other command lines?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `MemoryMXBean`, see [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) for details as it explains how to use it to get information on each `MemoryPool` (aka generation) and to get notifications when different events happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Btw it's not really what **I'm asking for**. I obtain the **same result** with my above `printMemUsage()` method. Give you +1 because some other methods of `MemoryMXBean` can help me ;)